# Wrong javascript array serialization in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, stripes

I want to pass array of javascript objects in ajax call.

I make my array this way:

```
   var itemsToEdit = [];
   $(".editedItem[value='true']").closest("tr").each(function() {
      var itemToEdit = {
         id: $(this).find(".idInput").val(),
         name: $(this).find(".nameInput").val(),
         code: $(this).find(".codeInput").val()
      }; // Represents SomeClass java class with fields: id, name, code
      itemsToEdit.push(itemToEdit);
   });
```

And then do ajax call:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "MyActionBean.action?saveChanges",
      type: "Post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: itemsToEdit,
      success: function( data ) {
         alert("Oh, no");
      }
   });
```

Problem is: on the server side I receive List of Maps, not the List of SomeClass objects.
I checked what browser sends and it is:

```
itemsToEdit[0][id]:4
itemsToEdit[0][name]:Florida
itemsToEdit[0][code]:FL
itemsToEdit[1][id]:3
itemsToEdit[1][name]:California
itemsToEdit[1][code]:CA
```

But I obviously want to have this, because I believe that this is right mapping to List of SomeClass:

```
itemsToEdit[0].id:4
itemsToEdit[0].name:Florida
itemsToEdit[0].code:FL
itemsToEdit[1].id:3
itemsToEdit[1].name:California
itemsToEdit[1].code:CA
```

Where am I wrong?

(Probably not important information to understand context: I use Stripes Framework and it maps parameters in request to called ActionBean fields)

Thank you!

Comment: `itemsToEdit[0][id]:4` and `itemsToEdit[0].id:4` UM, they means the same exact thing. Bracket and Dot Notation.

Comment: okay. But Stripes framework doesn't think so :) because the first variant is mapped by stripes to: private List<Map<String, String>> itemsToEdit; and second variant to: private List<SomeClass> itemsToEdit;

Comment: If you pass an array to `data:`, jQuery will hardly do what you did expect it to do. Have you checked the actual content of your POST requests?

Comment: yep. I specified it in my question. This is actual content of my POST request: itemsToEdit[0][id]:4 ... Even more, Stripes framework really maps it to the List<Map<String, String>>. I receive it on server side. And in jQuery ajax docs they say that you CAN pass arrays

Comment: @gs_vlad, did you found any solution for this problem?, I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple things that might be throwing stripes off.

1. Though nothing you're sending right now would cause issues, you should use `JSON.stringify()` on the data you're passing.
2. AJAX calls typically send JSON objects, not arrays.

Try sending and receiving your array like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyActionBean.action?saveChanges",
    type: "Post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'items': JSON.stringify(itemsToEdit)
    },
    success: function( data ) {
       alert("Oh, no");
    }
});
```

On the other side, retrieve the `items` property of the received object and parse that instead of the whole object.